# .NET Core stream.CopyToAsync taking long time

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

I am uploading 10 mb file using an ASP.NET Core Web API. Currently I have disabled form binding and trying to get stream from multipart.

In my local environment, everything works fine and the file is uploaded in less than 1 second. However on server `stream.CopyToAsyn(memorystream)` is taking at least 15 seconds. What can cause this delay on server?

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<BaseResponse> Upload()
{
        var response = new BaseResponse();

        if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
        {
            response.StatusCode = "500";
            response.Messages = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "Bad Request" };
            return response;
        }

        var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
            MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
            int.MaxValue);

        var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
        var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

        while (section != null)
        {
            var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition,
                 out var contentDisposition);

            if (hasContentDispositionHeader && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data") &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value))
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    var byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }

                return response;
            }

            section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }

        return response;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your memory in use when run on server?

Comment: Memory on the server is okay

Comment: Hi @VG18, you could try to use performance diagnostics tools, refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/diagnostic-tools?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Rena can we use this profiler to monitor application on server